# How to use logical indexing instead of for loops for mapping interpolated image values?

Tags: matlab, dictionary, image-processing, matrix, vectorization

My program transforms an original equirectangular image into an azimuthal orthographic projection.

This is done by locating every pixel on the projection image (destination) on the equirectangular image (input). Since the positions on the equirectangular image are often non inter numbers because of the projection (trigonomical and other functions) the color values of the projection images pixels have to be interpolated from the color values of the source image.

`im_source` is a 3 dimensional matrix, ordered by (row, column, color_channel), containing the value of the particular color channel

`m_source_q` is a 2 dimensional matrix, containing the row of the interpolation (query) grid, so for a 1024*512 original image and a grid precision of 0.1 pixels `m_source_q` looks like:

```
[1    1    1    1    ....  1
 1.1  1.1  1.1  1.1  ....  1.1
 1.2  1.2  1.2  1.2 .....  1.2
 ...
 512  512  512  512 ....   512]
```

`n_source_q` likewise contains the query column position

```
[1  1.1  1.2 1.3 .... 1024
 1  1.1  1.2 1.3 .... 1024
 ...
 1  1.1  1.2 1.3 .... 1024]
```

`p_er` is a 3-D matrix. it is a two-dimensional map that contains the fractioned coordinates of the interpolated original image for every pixel on the projection image. so for example `p_er(502, 262, 1) == 259.9` (corresponding row in original image); `p_er(592, 252, 2) == 513.2` (corresponding column in original image).

`imq` is a 3-D matrix that contains all interpolated color values for every color channel and for every grid position. `imq` is obtained by interpolation:

```
for idim=1:3
     imq(:,:,idim) = interp2(n_source, m_source, imsource(:,:,idim), n_source_q, m_source_q, 'linear');
end;
```

note that `idim` is the index of the color channel (R: 1, G: 2, B: 3)

`imp_double` is a 3-D matrix that contains the (double type / real number) color values of all color channels for every projection image pixel. this 
will just be converted to  `projection_image = uint8(imp_double)`.

The last step is mapping the projections pixels to the corresponding interpolated color values:

```
for idim=1:3
     imq_idim = imq(:,:,idim);
     for m=1:Hp        % Hp .. height of projection image
        for n=1:Wp    % Wp .. width of projection image
            if isRealPixel(m,n)
                imp_double(m,n,idim)=imq_idim(m_source_q==per(m,n,1) & n_source_q==per(m,n,2));
            end;
        end;
     end;
end;
```

This works, but it takes really too long, and I'm pretty sure that the two nested `for` loops are the cause of this.

My question: How can I avoid the for loops by logical indexing, or by some other method?

I tried

```
for idim=1:3
     imp_double(:,:,idim) = imq_idim(m_source_q==per(:,:,1) & n_source_q==per(:,:,2));
end;
```

but the interpreter complains the sizes of the matrices don't match. Apparently I have to tell MATLAB over what index vector (is that how you call it?) the function should be applied and the two colons are not sufficient. Do I need the matrices `m_source` and `n_source`, which are just the real source images row, rsp. col positions, for that purpose?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you able to execute `m_source_q==per(:,:,1) & n_source_q==per(:,:,2)` in your solution?

Comment: no, that doesn't work, the Error is: `Error using  ==
Matrix dimensions must agree.`

Comment: So for example if you try, `for idim=1:3; temp = m_source_q==per(:,:,1) & n_source_q==per(:,:,2); end;` you get that error?

Comment: `m_source_q` is 2D, and you are comparing it to a 3D matrix. Try [`squeeze`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html). For example `m_source_q==squeeze(per(:,:,1)) & n_source_q==squeeze(per(:,:,2))`. By the way, I have no idea what you are trying to do, just pointing to the possible dimension mismatch. Oh, and I see that `n_source_q` is 1D.. ok i have to read more, but keep in mind the dimensions

Comment: @BrendanFrick Yes, I get the same error.

Comment: So are you trying to find every item in `(m_source_q)` that exists in `per`?

Comment: @VaheTshitoyan I get the same error with squeeze. I checked the size of `per(:,:,1)` and `squeeze(per(:,:,1))`, they are the same. per(:,:,1) contains only the (fractional) row of the corresponding pixel in the projection image, per(:,:,2) the column, so per is actually more 2 combined 2-D matrices, but I see this might cause some confusion. I should rename them, eg. `per_m = per(:,:,1); per_n = per(:,:,2)`.

Comment: @BrendanFrick Actually my goal is to find an item in `imq` that is in the row where of the value `per(m,n,1)` matches `m_source_q` and the column where the value of `per` matches `n_source_q`, as a 2-dimensional reverse mapping

Comment: @peter, OK my solution should address that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Return indices of matrix A that match an item in matrix B

```
out = ismember(A,B);
```

out in this case will have the shape of A, and contains only items that are in both A and B.

#### Partial Solution

This assumes `imq_idim` is the same size as `m_source.` If that's not the case and `per(:,:,1)` is the same size as `img_idim` then flip the arguments.

This also assumes that what you are trying to do is find any `m_source` values that are in `per(:,:,1)`. If you are not trying to do this, then you also need to look at your looped solution, because that is what is currently happening there

```
for idim=1:3
   imp_double(:,:,idim) = imq_idim(ismember(m_source_q,per(:,:,1)) & ....
                                   ismember(n_source_q,per(:,:,2));
end;
```

#### Dimension Mismatch

The above code is correct on the right-side but won't pass to the left-side correctly in `imp_double(:,:,idim) = ...` %

**Left-side**

`imp_double(:,:,idim)` is asking for a matrix that is the same size as the first two dimensions of imp_double.

**Right-side**
 `imq_idim(ismember(m_source_q,per(:,:,1)) & ...                                     ismember(n_source_q,per(:,:,2));` returns a one-dimensional, variable sized vector (depends on how many matches we get).

**Solution**

*a)* Make the right-side a matrix `imp_double(:,:,idim)` but with correct values changed

```
% imp_double MUST BE PREALLOCATED
temp = imp_double(:,:,idim); % temp is a 2D matrix
temp(ismember(m_source_q,per(:,:,1)) & ....                                   
     ismember(n_source_q,per(:,:,2))) = ...
     imq_idim(ismember(m_source_q,per(:,:,1)) & ....
              ismember(n_source_q,per(:,:,2)));
imp_double(:,:,idim) ==  temp;
```

*b)* Specify the indices to be changed in `imp_double`

This would be the easy solution with something like the below. The problem is, you can't index a 3D matrix with a 2D logical followed by a 3rd index. Any solution here will be redundant with *a)* but slightly more complicated

```
% Doesn't work because can't index imp_double(mat,ind)
imp_double(ismember(m_source_q,per(:,:,1)) & ....                                   
           ismember(n_source_q,per(:,:,2)),...
           idim)) = ...
           imp_double(:,:,idim) = imq_idim(ismember(m_source_q,per(:,:,1)) & .... 
                                   ismember(n_source_q,per(:,:,2));
```

Comment: `ismember` really looks like the function I need! Thank you very much for that. I tried `imp_double(:,:,idim) = imq_idim(ismember(per(:,:,1) , m_source_q) & ismember(per(:,:,2) , n_source_q));` and it gave me a `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`, but I think that this could be caused by the complex non real numbers that I don't catch. I have to filter out non real values first.

Comment: No. That's actually another issue. The left hand and right hand arguments do not match. I'll add the fix